# Proceso almacenado SQL en C# usando programacion en capas Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, stored-procedure

Estoy desarrollando un progrma en capas en con #, quiero obtener la cantidad de filas de una tabla usando un proceso almacenado y luego pasarlo a una textbox, pero en lugar de aparecer el número de filas me aparece System.Dataset.DataSet, supongo que el resultado no se convirtió correctamente a String

Proceso almacenado

`CREATE PROCEDURE CCoM as SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Compras`

Código capa datos

```
 public DataSet ccom()
 {
     using (DataSet data = new DataSet())
     {
         conec = objConecta.Conecta();
         adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("CCoM", conec);
         adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         adaptador.Fill(data, "Compras");
         return data;
     }


 }
```

Capa negocios

```
public DataSet ccom()
{
    return comprasDAO.ccom();
}
```

Capa PRESENTACIÓN

```
  private void btnNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string filas= (string)capaNegociosCm.ccom().ToString();
           txtFilas.Text = filas;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Partes de una premisa equivocada, el [`DataSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0) no es el valor retornado por la consulta, sino un cache de datos en memoria, por lo que al hacer esto `ccom().ToString()` simplemente estas devolviendo la representación de la clase `DatSet` en una cadena. En la practica, puedes "llenar" un `DataSet` con múltiples consultas y acceder de manera independiente a cada una de ellas.

Yo te sugiero que en tu capa de negocios implementes un método más especifico que retorne el valor en sí, algo como esto:

```
public int getCantidadCompras()
{
    return comprasDAO.ccom().Tables["Compras"].Columns[0];
    // También podría ser así: comprasDAO.ccom().Tables[0].Columns[0];

}
```

Luego simplemente harías:

```
string filas = capaNegociosCm.getCantidadCompras().ToString();
```